# Linker error in Xcode 5.1 with cocos2d-x 3 beta 2

Tags: c++, xcode5, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

oday i tried to compile in Xcode 5.1 my sample app and i got linker error can someone tell me why is it happening ?

```
Ld /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Intermediates/Slot321.build/Debug-iphoneos/Slot321\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Slot321\ iOS normal arm64
    cd /Users/mmmssss/Documents/xcode5_projects/Slot321/Slot321/proj.ios_mac
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Intermediates/Slot321.build/Debug-iphoneos/Slot321\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Slot321\ iOS.LinkFileList -dead_strip -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libbox2d\ iOS.a /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libchipmunk\ iOS.a /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2dx\ iOS.a /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2dx-extensions\ iOS.a /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocosDenshion\ iOS.a -framework CoreMotion -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -lz -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Intermediates/Slot321.build/Debug-iphoneos/Slot321\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Slot321\ iOS_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mmmssss/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Slot321-ggaqzqgvjcazkuaqnngfqbbcfvvw/Build/Intermediates/Slot321.build/Debug-iphoneos/Slot321\ iOS.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Slot321\ iOS

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_WebPGetFeaturesInternal", referenced from:
      WebPGetFeatures(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, WebPBitstreamFeatures*) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_WebPDecode", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithWebpData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_TIFFGetField", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithTiffData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_TIFFClose", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithTiffData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_CreateDecompress", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_read_header", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithTiffData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_start_decompress", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_read_scanlines", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_destroy_decompress", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_WebPInitDecoderConfigInternal", referenced from:
      WebPInitDecoderConfig(WebPDecoderConfig*) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_read_info", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_std_error", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_image_width", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_set_packing", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_create_read_struct", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_image_height", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_set_palette_to_rgb", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_sig_cmp", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_valid", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_read_end", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_set_longjmp_fn", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "__TIFFfree", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithTiffData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_FT_Done_FreeType", referenced from:
      cocos2d::FontFreeType::shutdownFreeType() in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCFontFreeType.o)
  "_png_set_tRNS_to_alpha", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_rowbytes", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_read_update_info", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_jpeg_mem_src", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithJpgData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "__TIFFmalloc", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithTiffData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_set_strip_16", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_io_ptr", referenced from:
      cocos2d::(anonymous namespace)::pngReadCallback(png_struct_def*, unsigned char*, unsigned long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_set_read_fn", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_error", referenced from:
      cocos2d::(anonymous namespace)::pngReadCallback(png_struct_def*, unsigned char*, unsigned long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_bit_depth", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_get_color_type", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_destroy_read_struct", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_TIFFClientOpen", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithTiffData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
  "_png_read_image", referenced from:
      cocos2d::Image::initWithPngData(unsigned char const*, long) in libcocos2dx iOS.a(CCImage.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It looks like Cocos2d-x is including image libraries (PNG, JPEG, TIFF) that aren't compiled for 64-bit architecture. However, that doesn't explain to me why the same project will compile with Xcode 5.0.2 but not Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Wait, yes it does. Xcode 5.1 removed the option to compile without 64-bit support. In Xcode 5.0.2, the default is only to compile for 32-bit architectures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go your project settings, Build Settings, Architectures, and select "Other...". Modify the string to read `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)`.

Answer (score 4):

The last release of cocos2d-x (Cocos2d-x v3.0 rc0) fixes this issue. The new version adds arm64 support for XCode 5.1.

You should upgrade your project downloading the new version from [here](http://cdn.cocos2d-x.org/cocos2d-x-3.0rc0.zip).

More information can be found on the official [changelog](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/192).

Comment: Exactly, and you can specify linker flags to make it link with arm 64 versions of the libraries, as described here: http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/cocos2d-x-v3x-and-xcode-6x-with-arm-64.html

Answer (score 0):

Are those external libraries also compiled for `arm64`? Because if not, then you must disable it in Xcode settings e.g. making it `{ARCHS_STANDARD_32BIT}`

Comment: ...which would be because Xcode 5.1 removed the 32-bit compile option.

Answer (score -1):

Change your libraries version.

In my case, I change UIKit.framework, CoreMotion.framework and OpenGLES.framework libraries for iOS 7.1 version. (at Build Phases > LinkBinary With Libraries)

Delete red colored libraries and add new version of it.